# shared home with Mac OS

Tags: permissions, directory, home, macos

I have ubuntu (actually pop_os) and mac os on my laptop. To not get it too messy, some of my folders like documents, movie, music are used by both systems. The problem I encounter is due to the permissions though. Files created by mac are from user#501 and the group dialout. I tried to add my user to the group dialout, but with no success. I as well tried to change my linux user id to 501, but bricked my installation with it. Any advice for a newbie to smoothen this out?

Thanks:-)

Comment: I think you may be running into an issue where there are two types of users (regular and system). Linux convention [Debian at least] has >= 1000 for regular users and < 1000 for system users. For Ubuntu you may not see your user if it has a lower uid. I'm not familiar with Mac but it looks like Mac uses > 500 for regular users.  I would look to see if there's any way to change your Mac uid (even if you have to create a new user).

Comment: I heard Mac can be tricky to change UIS's. I tried to give my Mac User a new group with the UID from the one in Linux, but didn't figure out how to make all newI Files created as this group. Searching for this I came across ACL, with this it works so fare smooth:-)

Answer (score 0):

By accident I came across ACL, with that I could solve my problem.
On the Mac side I made a new Group with the same GID as the one in Linux. Terminal didn't work for me, I had to make a group in the System Preferences / Users & Gropus and added my Mac User to it. Then I set the ACL in order that all new content belongs to the Linux User Group.

```
sudo setfacl -d -R -m group:Groopname:rwx '/home/Userhome'
```

This works so far for me.

Comment: @Sturkater which filesystem format are you using for the shared directories? hfs? ext4? or?

Comment: first ext4, but then I got corrupted files when accessing it from my mac (using the paragon drivers). Now I use hfs+, but the driver for linux works around in 3 from 10 times. I think about switching over to do the setup with unraid.